# Agregar varias fechas a una variable (PHP-MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un formulario para ingresar datos de un curso:

```html
 <form action="creacion_curso_bd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" target="_self" id="form1">
      <div class="row form-group">

              <!-- nombre curso -->
       <div class="col-md-12">

          <input type="text" name="nombre_curso" id="nombre_curso" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del curso">
       </div> 
      
      </div> 

            <!-- fin nombre curso -->

            <input type="hidden" id="dir" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ip_usuario; ?>"> <!-- Podría ser <?=$ip?>, como fomra abreviada -->

     <!-- Fecha del curso -->         
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control required" type="text" name="check_in" id="check_in" placeholder="Fecha de realización">
                      </div>
                    </div>
            <!-- fin Fecha del curso -->


           <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="perdido" id="perdido" class="form-control" placeholder="---">
       </div>
      </div>


             <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="numero_horas" id="numero_horas" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad de horas" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);" >
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="sigper" id="sigper" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo SIGPER">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="vacantes" id="vacantes" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad de vacantes" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);" >
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="ubicacion" id="ubicacion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ubicación del curso">
              </div>
            </div>


            <!-- ambito -->
            <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select name="ambito" id="ambito" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
                    <option value=''>Elija un ambito</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM ambito");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_ambito].'">'.$valores[ambito].'</option>';
                        }
                       ?>

                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- fin ambito -->

            <!-- Relatores -->
      <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select name="id_relator" id="id_relator" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
                    <option value=''>Elija un relator</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM relatores");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_relator].'">'.$valores[nombre_relator].'</option>';
                        }
                       ?>

                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fin Relatores -->


      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" name="enviar" onclick="valida_envia()" value="Enviar inscripción" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar">
      </div>

     </form>
```

Sin embargo, me solicitaron modificar el campo de fecha, ya que un curso puede tener mas de 1 fecha de inscripción, por lo que necesito ver la forma de agregar varias fechas en una variable, y busco alguna manera de pasar, de un efecto de calendario a una especie de textbox,

He visto en sitios web especies de cuadros donde pasan información a otro cuadro (no se exactamente como se llaman)

Si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia, se lo agradecería mucho,

Saludos!!

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, quizá lo que necesites sea un array de fechas ¿?  o un `select` con varios `option` para cada posible fecha de un determinado curso  ¿? o varios `checkbox` con las fechas para seleccionar, en caso de que se puedan asignar varias fechas a un mismo curso de una misma persona ¿?  En este caso es importante que expliques con claridad cuál es el contexto porque lo que quieres se puede hacer de muchísimas maneras, pero ¿cuál sería la mejor? Eso lo define el contexto.

Comment: Estimado,

Para aclarar este punto, el sistema es de inscripción de cursos de capacitación, con un tabla para "cursos",

id_curso,
nombre_curso,
fechas_curso,
horas_curso,
id_ambito,
codigo_sigper,
vacantes,
ubicacion,
id_relator,

El id_ambito se refiere al ambito del curso (ej: computación, economia, etc...), y en las fechas_curso quiero agregar mas de una fecha ya que me solicitaron esa parte, debido a que un curso/capacitacion se puede desarrollar en una o varias fechas,

En el formulario actual, tengo un textbox con un jquery con efecto de calendario para fecha del curso..

Comment: .. pero ahora necesito agregar varias fechas en el curso/capacitación, por lo que estaba pensando agregar varias fechas en el campo fechas_curso, pero no se como llevar esto a un formulario html (desde cajas de texto ir guardando en un cuadro de mensaje para que se guarde en una variable $, ir pasando de una caja a otra....)

Comment: En ese caso lo que necesitarías es un `select` múltiple con las fechas que se pueden escoger. Cuando envías el dato, se enviará un array con todas las fechas que hayan sido seleccionadas.

Comment: Aclarar una cosa, el formulario donde me estan pidiendo cambios es el de "creación de curso" y no "inscripción", ya que en esta parte el admin tiene el atributo de introducir los datos del curso en cuestión, y el resto de usuarios ver que cursos estan disponibles. Ahora, lo que necesito es que el admin pueda agregar mas de 1 fecha al curso que esta creando